# Series expansion wrong

Tags: bugs, symbolic, series-expansion

I had to work with some series expansions lately, and at some point I realised that something was becoming inconsistent at some point. It seems that applying `Factor` broke my series expansions. Here's a minimal example extracted from my computations.

Consider the following expression

```
test =   Sqrt[1/(1 - x)] (Sqrt[1/(1 - x)] + 1) + 1;
```

Now look at those series expansions of `test` around `x=1`:

```
ser1 = Series[test // Factor, {x, 1, -1}]
ser2 = Series[test, {x, 1, -1}]
```

Not only are `ser1` and `ser2` different, but what's worse is that

```
ser2 - ser1
```

gives `1/(x-1) + O(x-1)^0`. At this point I would have expected `O(x-1)^0`, how come `Factor` can break a series expansion so much? Is this sort of behaviour a feature or a bug?

---

The problem seems to be in `ser2`, if one looks at `List@@ser2` one realises that `ser2` is saved as `a0+O(x-1)^2` with `a0` containing `x`, this seems to be the root of all evil.

Interestingly, if one alters `test` to

```
test =   1/Sqrt[(1 - x)] (1/Sqrt[(1 - x)] + 1) + 1;
```

which is really not much of a change, one obtains a different result. Given this instability, I don't know how I should trust the series expansions at all.

---

Here's a similar, but more subtle computation, which leads to two different results. Let's add `1/(1-x)` to `test`

```
test =  1/(1 - x) + 1/Sqrt[1 - x] (1/Sqrt[1 - x] + 1) + 1;
ser1 = Series[test // Factor, {x, 1, -1}];
ser2 = Series[test, {x, 1, -1}];
```

and compute

```
Limit[(1 - x) ser1, x -> 1] (* = 2 *)
Limit[(1 - x) ser2, x -> 1] (* = 1 *)
```

In a realistic scenario `test` would be much more complicated, and I wouldn't compute both `ser1` and `ser2` and then compare, but just one of them. So there's a 50/50 chance that I'd obtain a wrong result without being aware of it.

---

Mathematica Version : 11.1 .0 .0

Platform : Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit kernel)

Comment: [This is what I get when I run your code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P0v4.png) It doesn't seem to be different.

Comment: @march strange, I just created a new kernel and ran my code there, still the same result. Which Mathematica version do you have? I just added my version to the original post.

Comment: V10.0.1, Mac OSX.

Comment: By the way, I've removed the `bugs` tag for now. As mentioned in the `bugs` tag statement, it is only used when the bug is validated by the community here. It seems like a bug, but let's let the expert community decide.

Comment: @march  With V11.2 on Windows 10 (64bit), I do not reproduce your result.  The issue, as I see it, is that `ser1` and `ser2` are to different orders.  If I change the definition of `ser1` so that the resulting series is the same order as that in `ser2`, I obtain the same result.  So, I do not think this is a bug.

Comment: What is strange is that `Series` produces a series to order `+1` in `ser2`, whereas a series to order `-1` is requested.

Comment: I think this is related to `Sqrt`. Try to see if the same happens using `Power`.

Answer (score 10):

I think the behavior described is a bug, and I think it is related to the new enhanced support of [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) in [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit). In M11.1 we have:

```
Series[1 + (1 + Sqrt[1/(1-x)]) Sqrt[1/(1-x)] , {x, 1, 3}] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{x-1}}+1+O\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right)$

Note how the terms are powers of $x-1$. If we tell M11.1 that $x<1$, we get:

```
Series[1 + (1 + Sqrt[1/(1-x)])  Sqrt[1/(1-x)], {x, 1, 3}, Assumptions->x<1] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{x-1}}+1+O\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right)$

which is the same as before, even though we might wish to have a power series in $1-x$. Now, in M11.2, we have:

```
Series[1 + (1 + Sqrt[1/(1-x)]) Sqrt[1/(1-x)], {x, 1, 3}, Assumptions->x>1] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{x-1}}+1+O\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right)$

```
Series[1 + (1 + Sqrt[1/(1-x)]) Sqrt[1/(1-x)], {x, 1, 3}, Assumptions->x<1] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}+\frac{1}{1-x}+1\right)+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$

Notice that the `Assumptions -> x>1` version returns what M11.1 did, while the `Assumptions -> x<1` version has the issues described in the OP. In particular, we see that Series is trying to create a power series in $1-x$ (note the `Sqrt[1-x]` and `1/(1-x)` terms), but the overall SeriesData object is a power series in $x-1$, and so problems arise.

Until these issues are worked out, it might make sense to use `Assumptions->x>1` in your code.

Comment: The use of fractional powers in `1-x` is actually a bug fix (many bug fixes, really). Some of the details, such as integer powers of `1-x` appearing in the `SeriesData` object coefficients, do appear to be amiss. (Maybe you knew this, but I would guess some readers did not.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  When all is said and done, do you judge the behavior here to be a bug?  If so, do you or CarlWolf wish to report it, or shall I?  Thanks,

Comment: (1) @bgodfrey I added the "bugs" tag, so yes, I regard appearance of such integer powers in the coefficients as a bug. I reported it. Should be fixed for the next release.

Comment: (2) As best I am aware, @CarlWoll is not actually a wolf. But I should mention I've never seen him during a full moon.

Answer (score 7):

This seemingly simple problem indeed produces unexpected results:

```
ser1 = Series[test // Factor, {x, 1, -1}]
(* -(1/(x - 1)) + SeriesData[x, 1, {}, -1, 0, 1] *)
ser2 = Series[test, {x, 1, -1}]
(* SeriesData[x, 1, {1 + ((1 - x)^(-1))^Rational[1, 2] + (1 - x)^(-1)}, 0, 2, 1] *)
```

Note that `ser1` is a series of order `-1`, as requested, whereas `ser2` is a series of order `+1`.  Compare

```
ser3 = Series[test // Factor, {x, 1, 1}] 
(* SeriesData[x, 1, {-1, 1 + ((1 - x)^(-1))^Rational[1, 2]}, -1, 2, 1] *)
```

which is mathematically the same as `ser2`, although its Mathematica internal representation is different.  So one question is, why does Mathematica return series of different orders for ostensibly the same problem.

It also is worth noting that

```
ser2 - ser1
(* 1/(x - 1) + SeriesData[x, 1, {}, -1, 0, 1] *)
```

because Mathematica discards higher order terms, until both expressions are of the same order, as it should.  It may be helpful to see the expressions as they actually appear on the screen:

[image]

**Addendum:**

Both the original question and the recent addition to it involve series expansions about a branch point, which invites problems.  In fact, there is no well defined series about a branch point, unless additional conditions are imposed.  On the other hand, adding an extra condition in the form of `Assumptions -> x <= 1` to the original problem yields the same result as before.

Now, explicitly consider the new addition to the question:

```
test = 1/(1 - x) + 1/Sqrt[1 - x] (1/Sqrt[1 - x] + 1) + 1; 
ser1 = Series[test // Factor, {x, 1, -1}]
(* SeriesData[x, 1, {-2 - (1 - x)^Rational[1, 2]}, -1, 0, 1] *)
ser2 = Series[test, {x, 1, -1}]
(* -(1/(x - 1)) + SeriesData[x, 1, {}, -1, 0, 1] *)
```

Again, for clarity this is how this material appears on the screen.

[image]

The two results ostensibly are to the same order and, hence, can be compared directly.  `ser2` is incorrect.  Also, `Assumptions -> x <= 1` does not help.  This appears to be a bug.

**Progress Report**: Version 11.3 produces the same results as in the addendum

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the way, I just updated my original question with an additional example, in which the consequences are more subtle, but also harder to detect in a real-life setting.

Comment: That `(1 - x)^(-1)` inside the coefficient list for `ser2` looks suspect. Will investigate (next week).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Please do.  This looks like a bug to me, new to Version 11.  However, I shall hold off adding a bug header until you have a chance to weigh in.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  The problem persists with Version 11.3.

Comment: I'll take another look...

Comment: I think the issue remaining in 11.3 is the same as noted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170652/when-to-trust-series) and [also here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163423/series-expansion-gives-incorrect-result). All three behave better in the current devel code and, barring trouble appearing in testing (which has not happened as yet) the fixes will appear in the next release.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in 12.1

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

```
ClearAll[x]
test = Sqrt[1/(1 - x)] (Sqrt[1/(1 - x)] + 1) + 1;
ser1 = Series[test // Factor, {x, 1, -1}];
ser2 = Series[test, {x, 1, -1}];
ser2 === ser1
```