# Series expansion gives incorrect result

Tags: bugs, complex, series-expansion

**Bug introduced after 10.4 and persisting through 11.3.0**

---

Mathematica 11.1.1.0 tells me that

```
In: Series[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]])/
       (x + Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]]), {x, Infinity, 0}]
Out: 1 + O[1/x]^1
```

instead of the correct answer
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x-\sqrt{1+x^2|a|^2}}{x+\sqrt{1+x^2|a|^2}}=\frac{1-|a|}{1+|a|}.$$

I can get the right answer if I replace `a*Conjugate[a]` by `Abs[a]^2` but that should not make a difference. Replacing `a*Conjugate[a]` by `a^2` still gives the wrong answer.

Q: Is this a known/predictable issue with `Series` and how can I avoid this? (Using `Limit` instead of `Series` is one suggested work around.)

Comment: What's the actual question here? Nevertheless: `Limit[expr, x -> Infinity] // FullSimplify // Together` gives the desired output.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, because in v10.4 `Series[expr, {x, Infinity, 0}] // Normal // FullSimplify // Together` gives the correct output, but v11.1 indeed gives `1`. Someone else could check if it's the case in v11.2. I'm adding the bugs tag.

Comment: v11.2 returns `1 + a Conjugate[a] + O[1/x]`.

Comment: There is no Mathematica v10.5

Comment: thank you, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought the issue was that there wasn't an assumption built in that says $a\,\bar a$ is a nonnegative real.

```
Series[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]])/(x + Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]]), {x, ∞, 0}, 
 Assumptions -> a*Conjugate[a] >= 0]

(* SeriesData[x, DirectedInfinity[1], {(1 - Abs[a])/(1 + Abs[a])}, 0, 1, 1] *)
```

But after further investigation, it seems the proper way to view the issue is that the assumption that `x` is positive is probably not made at some critical point:

```
Series[
 (x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]])/(x + Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]]),
 {x, Infinity, 0}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
(*
SeriesData[x, DirectedInfinity[1],
 {(1 - (a Conjugate[a])^Rational[1, 2])/(1 + (a Conjugate[a])^Rational[1, 2])},
 0, 1, 1]
*)
```

Note that the following is a simpler example with the same bug:

```
Series[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*z])/(x + Sqrt[1 + x^2*z]), {x, Infinity, 0}]
(*  SeriesData[x, DirectedInfinity[1], {1 + z}, 0, 1, 1]  (wrong) *)

Limit[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*z])/(x + Sqrt[1 + x^2*z]), x -> Infinity]
(*  (1 - Sqrt[z])/(1 + Sqrt[z])  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version
(* 11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)*)
```

.

```
Series[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]])/(x + Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]]), 
{x, Infinity, 0}]//Normal

(* 1 + a Conjugate[a] *) ?
```

Adding assumptions:

```
Series[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]])/(x + 
Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]]), {x, Infinity, 0}, 
Assumptions -> {a != 0}]

(* 1 + a Conjugate[a] *) ?
```

.

Adding `Assumptions -> {a != 0}` solved the problem in case if I replace `a*Conjugate[a]` by `Abs[a]^2`.

```
Series[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*Abs[a]^2])/(x + Sqrt[1 + x^2*Abs[a]^2]), {x, 
Infinity, 0}, Assumptions -> {a != 0}]
```

> $$\frac{1-\left| a\right| }{1+\left| a\right| }+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^1\right)$$

In Mathematica 10.2 gives:

```
Series[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]])/(x + 
Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]]), {x, Infinity, 0}] // Normal // 
FullSimplify // Together
```

> $\frac{1-\left| a\right| }{1+\left| a\right| }$

With Assumptions:

```
Series[(x - Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]])/(x + 
Sqrt[1 + x^2*a*Conjugate[a]]), {x, Infinity, 0}, 
Assumptions -> a != 0] // Normal // FullSimplify // Together
```

> $\frac{1-\left| a\right| }{1+\left| a\right| }$

Comment: Did the first command really give `1 + a Conjugate[a]`? This looks weird.

Comment: @corey979 Yes did.

Comment: I mean that the $1+aa^*$ result is not very similar to the outputs of v10.2/10.4/11.1; looks like things went really bad in v11...