# When to trust Series

Tags: bugs, series-expansion

I want to evaluate this function near `x=1`:

```
g[x_] := (-2 + 115*x^2 + 616*x^4 + 216*x^6)/(-1 + x^2)^5 + 
    (3*x^2*(12 + 159*x^2 + 136*x^4 + 8*x^6)*ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]])/(1 - x^2)^(11/2);
```

The following seems to give a good representation of the function near `dx=x-1=0` and you can see from the plot why I want to use a series expansion to evaluate near `x=1`:

```
gdx0 = Series[g[1 + dx], {dx, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> dx > 0]
```

$\frac{16}{1155}-\frac{64 \text{dx}}{65}+O\left(\text{dx}^2\right)$

```
Plot[{g[1 + dx], Evaluate[Normal[gdx0]]}, {dx, -0.02, 0.02}]
```

[image]

However, if I expand about `x=1`, there is trouble with simplifying even specifying that `x>1` (which implies that `x` is real):

```
gx1 = Series[g[x], {x, 1, 5}, Assumptions -> x > 1]
```

$\frac{945}{32 (x-1)^5}+\frac{3255}{64 (x-1)^4}+\frac{2479}{128 (x-1)^3}-\frac{123}{256 (x-1)^2}+\frac{123}{256 (x-1)}-\frac{269}{512}+\frac{945 i \sqrt{x-1}}{32 (1-x)^{11/2}}-\frac{183 (x-1)}{1024}+\frac{3255 i (x-1)^{3/2}}{64 (1-x)^{11/2}}+\frac{1443 (x-1)^2}{2048}+\frac{2479 i (x-1)^{5/2}}{128 (1-x)^{11/2}}-\frac{6497 (x-1)^3}{8192}-\frac{123 i (x-1)^{7/2}}{256 (1-x)^{11/2}}+\frac{9729 (x-1)^4}{16384}+\frac{123 i (x-1)^{9/2}}{256 (1-x)^{11/2}}-\frac{10167 (x-1)^5}{32768}+O\left((x-1)^{11/2}\right)$

I get the same result with `FullSimplify[gx1, x > 1]`. Note that the constant term is not correct (see `gdx0` above). By taking the `Normal` part of the series it can simplify, but gives the wrong result:

```
Expand[FullSimplify[Normal[gx1] /. x -> 1 + dx, dx > 0]]
```

$-\frac{10167 \text{dx}^5}{32768}+\frac{9729 \text{dx}^4}{16384}-\frac{6497 \text{dx}^3}{8192}+\frac{1443 \text{dx}^2}{2048}-\frac{183 \text{dx}}{1024}-\frac{269}{512}$

If I include enough terms, `n`, then eventually the first two terms are correct, but for small `n` there are extraneous terms in $\mathrm{dx}^{-1}$:

```
Table[Expand[
   FullSimplify[
    Normal[Series[g[x], {x, 1, n}, Assumptions -> x > 1]] /. 
     x -> 1 + dx, dx > 0]], {n, 0, 7}] // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{945}{32 \text{dx}^5}+\frac{3255}{64 \text{dx}^4}+\frac{2479}{128 \text{dx}^3}-\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}^2}+\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}}-\frac{269}{512}\\
\frac{3255}{64 \text{dx}^4}+\frac{2479}{128 \text{dx}^3}-\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}^2}-\frac{183 \text{dx}}{1024}+\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}}-\frac{269}{512}\\
\frac{2479}{128 \text{dx}^3}+\frac{1443 \text{dx}^2}{2048}-\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}^2}-\frac{183 \text{dx}}{1024}+\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}}-\frac{269}{512}\\
-\frac{6497 \text{dx}^3}{8192}+\frac{1443 \text{dx}^2}{2048}-\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}^2}-\frac{183 \text{dx}}{1024}+\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}}-\frac{269}{512}\\
\frac{9729 \text{dx}^4}{16384}-\frac{6497 \text{dx}^3}{8192}+\frac{1443 \text{dx}^2}{2048}-\frac{183 \text{dx}}{1024}+\frac{123}{256 \text{dx}}-\frac{269}{512}\\
-\frac{10167 \text{dx}^5}{32768}+\frac{9729 \text{dx}^4}{16384}-\frac{6497 \text{dx}^3}{8192}+\frac{1443 \text{dx}^2}{2048}-\frac{183 \text{dx}}{1024}-\frac{269}{512}\\
\frac{4451 \text{dx}^6}{65536}-\frac{10167 \text{dx}^5}{32768}+\frac{9729 \text{dx}^4}{16384}-\frac{6497 \text{dx}^3}{8192}+\frac{1443 \text{dx}^2}{2048}-\frac{183 \text{dx}}{1024}+\frac{16}{1155}\\
\frac{2931 \text{dx}^7}{32768}+\frac{4451 \text{dx}^6}{65536}-\frac{10167 \text{dx}^5}{32768}+\frac{9729 \text{dx}^4}{16384}-\frac{6497 \text{dx}^3}{8192}+\frac{1443 \text{dx}^2}{2048}-\frac{64 \text{dx}}{65}+\frac{16}{1155}\end{pmatrix}$

Overall, the problem seems to be that it's not treating terms like $\frac{i\sqrt{x-1}}{(1-x)^{11/2}}$ as the correct order in the series, so without asking for sufficient order, the summation/cancellation of different terms of the same order isn't happening.

My single question is: how do I ask Mathematica for a series in a way that is sure to be safe when not expanding about zero?

EDIT in response to answer by Ulrich Neumann:

I'm using v11.2.0.0. For the `Plot` of `gS` (copy and pasted exactly as suggested), this gives:

[image]

This may relate to the comment by Akku14, i.e. perhaps Ulrich is using an older version than me. In any case, it is perhaps more general to use `Series[g[a + d], {d, a, 1}, Assumptions -> d > 0]` to workaround the bug, rather than pulling out removable singularities.

Comment: Something weird is indeed going on. Would you mind explaining where the function came from?

Comment: It is `x^2 D[y/3, {x, 4}]` where `y=3x^2 ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]/(1 - x^2)^(3/2) - (1 + 2 x^2)/(1 - x^2)`. `y` is the result of an integral of a rational function.

Comment: It does look like you need to use enough terms: `res = Assuming[x > 1, FullSimplify[x^2 D[Series[x^2 ArcSech[x]/(1 - x^2)^(3/2) - (1 + 2 x^2)/(3 (1 - x^2)), {x, 1, 10}], {x, 4}]]]; Assuming[x > 1, Series[Normal[res], {x, 1, 6}]]`

Comment: Yes, your equation gives the correct constant term but incorrect linear and higher terms. That's also what the end of the `Table` shows in the question: include even more terms and the linear term is correct, etc. But it doesn't seem obvious a priori how many terms need to be included to get a certain number of correct terms. Might this be a bug?

Comment: Yes, I think it is one.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll contact http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback.

Comment: MMA Version 8.0 gives the right series expansion gx1 to any order. Looks like a bug in higher versions.

Comment: _v9.0.1_ gives the correct result.

Comment: I'm not certain, but this may be the same underlying issue as appeared [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163423/series-expansion-gives-incorrect-result). I expect an improvement will be in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

If you factor out the the singularity `(x-1)^5` and expand `g[x] (-1 + x^2)^5`

```
gS = Normal[Series[g[x] (-1 + x^2)^5, {x, 1, 5 }]]
```

Mathematica evaluates as expected

```
Show[{Plot[gS/(-1 + x^2)^5, {x, 1 - #, 1 + #}], 
Graphics[{Red, Point[{1, Limit[g[x], x -> 1]}]}]}] &[.001]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in my version. My edited question has details. Does your version show the behaviour I outline in my original question?

Comment: @Ramashalanka: My MMA version is 11.0.1 (Windows). This version doesn't show the behaviour `gx1=...` Plot-behaviour is the same.